# Level out a list of lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to level out in Racket a list made out of lists and list of lists. The original list looks like:

```
'(((a 1) (b 2)) (c 3) ((d 4) (e 5)))
```

I need it to be like:

```
'((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5))
```

I've tried with flatten, concatenate, etc and I get different things but not this one:

```
(define KK '(((a 1)(b 2))(c 3)((d 4)(e 5))))

(map(lambda(x)(if (list? x) x (list x)))(concatenate KK))

'((a 1) (b 2) (c) (3) (d 4) (e 5))

(map(lambda(x)x)(concatenate KK))

'((a 1) (b 2) c 3 (d 4) (e 5))

(map(lambda(x)(if (list? (car x)) (ormap(lambda(y)(when (list? y) y)) x) x))KK)

'((a 1) (c 3) (d 4))

(map(lambda(x)(if (list? (car x)) (andmap(lambda(y)(when (list? y) y)) x) 
x))KK)

'((b 2) (c 3) (e 5))
```

The closer I got is the last two, but I have missing values, because it is a boolean map. Map packs the result in a single list.

EDIT: My main problem is that the list is created by a function that depending on the input, the output is a single list or a list of 2 to n lists:

Let a list called H be composed of 2 to n elements. Let SPECS be a list made out of lists with the possible combinations of the elements of H that matches condition C. For example:

```
H='(a 1)
```

So, being '* a symbol that semantically means a wild car, let all combinations of elements in H to be:

```
HHs='((* *) (a *)(* 1) (a 1))
```

So SPECS are the HHs that meets some conditions, for example: '((a *)(* 1))

```
(map (lambda(S)(when  (<condition>)(set! NEWSET (append NEWSET S))))SPECS)
```

If I trace S I see this:

```
S1: (((*) (-inf.0 9) (2 +inf.0) (*)) ((*) (9 30) (2 +inf.0) (*)))
S2: ((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (*))
S3: (((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (no)) ((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (si)))
S4: (((soleado) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)) ((nublado) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)) ((lluvioso) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)))
```

So if I pack them in a list, I have:

```
'((((*) (-inf.0 9) (2 +inf.0) (*)) ((*) (9 30) (2 +inf.0) (*)))
   ((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (*))
   (((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (no)) ((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (si)))
   (((soleado) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)) ((nublado) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)) ((lluvioso) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*))))
```

But I would need instead:

```
'(((*) (-inf.0 9) (2 +inf.0) (*)) ((*) (9 30) (2 +inf.0) (*))((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (*))((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (no)) ((*) (-inf.0 30) (2 +inf.0) (si))((sunny) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)) ((cloudy) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)) ((rainy) (-inf.0 30) (*) (*)))
```

(having the elements of the lists in () it's just a semantic of my algorythm).

Regards

Comment: `((λ (l) (append-map (λ (ll) (if (andmap list? ll) ll (list ll))) l)) '(((a 1) (b 2)) (c 3) ((d 4) (e 5))))`

Comment: Can you say more about the shape the data should have? What determines when a sublist shouldn't be flattened? Like, the `(z 0)`, `(a 1)`, `(b 2)`, etc. aren't flattened in your examples. The other answers so far have assumed that the thing that determines those is being two-element lists, but you've said the sublists are 1 to _n_ elements. If it's not that, then what does determine it?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. A certain function recursively can output a single list with e elements, such like 
    '(z 0)
or a list of 2-to-n lists of e elements, such like 
    '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5))
No matter how big the length e is. At the end of the recursions, all single lists and list of 2-to-n lists are returned all packed in a outer list. So I have a list with single sublists + sublists of 2-to-n lists:    '(((a 1) (b 2)) (c 3) ((d 4) (e 5)))  I need to put all 2-to-n lists as single lists outside the list of lists. So at the end I will have just a list of single lists.

Comment: Such like:  '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) ((d 4) (e 5))

Comment: Okay, what is the exact shape a "single list" as you put it? Is it a list of exactly two elements? Or is it more general than that? Can you give examples of "single list" things that aren't two element lists? Or examples of two-element lists that aren't "single list" values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a one-liner, built-in procedure to solve this for the general case of an arbitrarily nested list. Here's a possible solution using an explicit loop, assuming that the list contains two-element sublists at all levels:

```
(define (level-out lst)
  (let loop ([lst (flatten lst)])
    (if (empty? lst)
        '()
        (cons (list (first lst) (second lst))
              (loop (rest (rest lst)))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(level-out '(((a 1) (b 2)) (c 3) ((d 4) (e 5))))
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5))

(level-out '((((((a 1)))))))
=> '((a 1))

(level-out '())
=> '()

(level-out '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5)))
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5))
```

Comment: Thx @Óscar López. I forgot to mention the sublists are from 1 to n elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html). Note that the **assumption** here is that the inner list that we're lifting up is a list of 2 things.

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(define (flat-lift l)
  (match (flatten l)
    ['() '()]
    [(cons a (cons b c)) (cons (list a b) (flat-lift c))]))

(check-equal? (flat-lift '(((a 1) (b 2)) (c 3) ((d 4) (e 5))))
              '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5)))

(check-equal? (flat-lift '((((((a 1))))))) '((a 1)))

(check-equal? (flat-lift '()) '())

(check-equal? (flat-lift '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5)))
              '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5)))
```

Comment: Thx Atharva. I forgot to mention the sublists are from 1 to n elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a predicate that determines when a sublist shouldn't be flattened, then you can do this.

```
;; An Element is a value for which element? returns true
;; element? : Any -> Boolean
(define (element? v)
  ...you-have-to-determine-this...)
```

This `element?` predicate should answer the question, "What determines when a sublist shouldn't be flattened?" Like, the `(z 0)`, `(a 1)`, `(b 2)`, etc. aren't flattened in your examples. The other answers so far have assumed that the thing that determines those is being two-element lists, but you've said the sublists are 1 to n elements. Whatever the shape of those that distinguishes them from normal nested lists, you should define `element?` to recognize that.

If you determine this `element?` predicate, then you can make a flatten function based on it:

```
;; A NestedListofElement is one of:
;;  - Element
;;  - [Listof NestedListofElement]

;; flatten-elements : NestedListofElement -> [Listof Element]
(define (flatten-elements nle)
  (cond
    [(element? nle) (list nle)]
    [(list? nle)    (append-map flatten-elements nle)]))
```